# Rails action being called twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, action, rails-admin

As the title says, my action is being fired twice when clicked a single time.
The action is just meant for copying a model then saving the copied model.

```
module RailsAdmin
  module Config
    module Actions
      class CopyAction < RailsAdmin::Config::Actions::Base
        RailsAdmin::Config::Actions.register(self)

        register_instance_option :member do
          true
        end

        register_instance_option :http_methods do
          [:get]
        end

        register_instance_option :controller do
          proc do
            if request.get? # EDIT
              @newObject = @object.dup
              objectNameCopy = @object.name + "_copy_"
              @queues = Filter.where('name LIKE ?',"%#{objectNameCopy}%")
              x = 1

              @queues.each do |q|
                x=x+1
              end
              @newObject.name = @newObject.name + "_copy_" + x.to_s
              @newObject.key = @newObject.key + "_copy_" + x.to_s
              if @newObject.save!
                respond_to do |format|
                  format.html { redirect_to_on_success }
                end
              else
                @newObject.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
                  flash.now[:error] = message
                end
              end
            end
          end
        end

        register_instance_option :link_icon do
          'fa fa-copy'
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I have noticed that by entering the URL manually, it works as intended.
When clicking the icon to run this action, it opens a URL with a `#` at the end. I've not a clue where this could be coming from.

Comment: Might want to add your view code.  Also, is there any javascript being used on the view?

Comment: I'm 99% sure its due to a rogue javascript click handler or a turbolinks issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a @max said in the comments its probably a turbolinks issue, try disabling it for your action like this

```
module RailsAdmin
  module Config
    module Actions
      class CopyAction < RailsAdmin::Config::Actions::Base
        RailsAdmin::Config::Actions.register(self)
   
        # ADD THIS
        register_instance_option :pjax? do
          false
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```